# Task rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, android, executorservice

My database:

```
@Database(entities = {Sensor.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class LocalDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract SensorDao sensorDao();

    private static volatile LocalDatabase INSTANCE;
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 4;
    static final ExecutorService databaseWriteExecutor =
            Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);

    static LocalDatabase getDatabase(final Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (LocalDatabase.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            LocalDatabase.class, "efento-database")
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

}
```

RecyclerView Adapter (gives error):

```
registerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String mac = devices.get(getLayoutPosition()).getAddress();
                    if(!regSensors.contains(mac)) {
                        LocalDatabase.databaseWriteExecutor.execute(() -> {
                            LocalDatabase.getDatabase(context).sensorDao().insertSensor(new Sensor(mac));
                        });
                        registerBtn.setText("Unregister");
                    }
                }
            });
```

Main Activty (this runs fine):

```
LocalDatabase.databaseWriteExecutor.execute(() -> {
            db = LocalDatabase.getDatabase(this);
            sensorDao = db.sensorDao();
            regSensors = (ArrayList<String>) sensorDao.getAllAddress();
        });
        LocalDatabase.databaseWriteExecutor.shutdown();
        try {
            LocalDatabase.databaseWriteExecutor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {  }
```

Error:

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task com.hamza.enfentodb.bleListAdapter$ViewHolder$1$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0@4ed5679 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@3fcdfbe[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2085)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:848)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1394)
        at com.hamza.enfentodb.bleListAdapter$ViewHolder$1.onClick(bleListAdapter.java:42)
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error. I doubt its due to the executorService.shutdown(). I need to use that in MainActivity to make sure I get the regSensor List before continuing.

Comment: `I doubt its due to the executorService.shutdown()` - why, the error states its "Terminated" after completing a single task?  "I need to use that in MainActivity to make sure I get the regSensor List before continuing" - you need to shutdown an executor service to do what?  Sounds like a code smell.

Comment: @Mark I need to make sure that the thread completes so I have the database initialized and I can make the query to get the data.

Comment: This is a classic case of where you should be using some sort of Oberver pattern, currently you have a ui interacting directly with the domain, and introducing hacks so you can read some data - again to me this is a code smell.

Comment: I would implement an observer but the data in my database isnt meant to change only Insertion needs to be done in my app. I just need to get whatever is in the database on start and display it, then ocasionally add entries. Should I still implement an observer?